# Why does this particular std::map initialization work?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to understand how to initialize std::map. I saw the following way of initializing map on the web (Note the `Test& t = mylist[0]` part):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
  public:
   Test():i_(0) { cout<<"Calling constructor"<<endl;}
   ~Test() { cout <<"Calling destructor"<<endl;}
  private:
   int i_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  map<unsigned,Test> mylist;
  cout << "Before "<<mylist.size()<<endl;
  Test& t = mylist[0];
  cout << "After "<<mylist.size()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Naively, I would have expected the following to work,

```
Test t;
mylist[0] = t;
```

But it hurts my brain to think why the first method just works! How is the object getting initialized? Is it a temporary since technically writing the expression`mylist[0];` alone would create an object (but how?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `operator[]` inserts it into the map if it's not present. Thus, there's a valid object in the map for the reference.

Comment: @chris Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @chris Thanks a bunch! I looked up the operator[] and it sure does insert a new element if not present. Cheers!

Comment: @covariantmonkey That's because he posted it as a comment rather than an answer.  I was trying to say with my comment that he should post it as an answer as well.

Comment: @Corbin, It could be fleshed out a little. I'm sure the answers there and to come will do a good job of that.

Comment: @chris I assumed it would be elaborated on a bit, but hey, was just trying to push you in the direction of rep.  Sometimes these short little questions end up getting a weirdly high amount of votes on the answer.  (And yes, I'm secretly a massive rep whore.... lol)

Comment: @Corbin, I know what you mean. I don't answer too many normally anyway, and lately, I've stuck to comments even more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [**cppreference.com**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/):

> [[**std::map::operator[]**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)] Inserts a new element to the container using key as the key and a default constructed mapped value and returns a reference to the newly constructed mapped value. If an element with key `key` already exists, no insertion is performed and a reference to its mapped value is returned.

This means that when `Test& t = mylist[0];` is executed, `Test()` is called (you will have seen "Calling constructor") and this object was inserted into the `map` "`mylist`" with a key of `0`. Since there is no element in the map with that key at the time this is called, this operation increases the size of `mylist` by exactly one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the `[]` operator on std::map will create a new object using the value class's default constructor.

[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/)/:

> If x does not match the key of any element in the container, the
>   function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference
>   to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the map size by
>   one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element
>   is constructed using its default constructor).

If the class does not have a default constructor there will be a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know about the default constructor.